# How to configure this to correct translations?

Tags: interface, customization

How to configure this to correct translations? in I18n Branches

I found a total of 35 words or mistranslated instructions in my language, how can I configure this to correct them?
since when clicking on the place where the correction should be made and select Edit Translation, it tells me that it can not be edited, and that I need to edit in the source code which is in

> all tools found in trunk / po / bl_i18n_utils dir (which is actually
>   linked from Blender's source code repository)!

When you find out this, you send me to these links but I do not have the slightest idea of what to do, I really did not understand it

[image]
[image]

[bf-translations - Revision 4940: /](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-translations)

[bf-translations - Revision 4939: /](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-translations/)

Cos

Comment: relevant https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Translate_Blender

Comment: if I understood the blender wiki I would not come here and ask for a more detailed example of how to apply it or apply it

Comment: but i solve a few days, thanks